# How To Get Sequential Result from Async Multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to get a sequenced list through some web API by multithreading. The sequence of each page is really important and I have to keep them.

Here's my sequential code:

```py
def get_all_items(max_count):
    res = []
    curr_page = 1
    per_page = 100
    while True:
        try:
            pagination_list = get_pagination_list(page=curr_page, per_page=per_page)  # Assume this is a 3rd-party API, slow Network IO
        except Exception:
            break
        if not pagination_list:
            break
        if (curr_page - 1) * per_page > max_count:
            break
        # ... and other conditions to break, lets just make it simple

        res.extend(pagination_list)
        curr_page += 1

    return res
```

My current idea is to use a dict { [curr_page]: [pagination_list] } to make the list sequenced, but I don't know what to do to replace the `break` logic with `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `threading`. Also, the created threads need to be finished.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import math

def get_pagination_list(page, per_page):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if page >= 4: # Suppose the server only ever returns 4 pages of results
        return []
    return [f"Result {i} in page {page}." for i in range(per_page)]


def get_all_items(max_count=999):
    per_page = 6
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        futures = {}
        for i in range(math.ceil(max_count/per_page)):
            future = executor.submit(get_pagination_list, page=i, per_page=per_page)
            futures[future] = i
            
        results = {}
        count = 0
        for completed_future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                result = completed_future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc) # Any exceptions raised in get_pagination_list are raised again when completed_future.result() is called
            else:
                count += len(result)
                print("Count:", count)
                # If the page is empty or we have reached the max number of results we should cancel all the other futures
                if not result or count >= max_count:
                    for future in futures:
                        cancelled = future.cancel()
                        # "If the call is currently being executed or finished running and cannot be cancelled then the method will 
                        # return False, otherwise the call will be cancelled and the method will return True."
                        # These 3 lines below can be deleted.
                        if cancelled:
                            page_number = futures[future]
                            print(f"Successfully cancelled future for page {page_number}", future)
                page_number = futures[completed_future]
                results[page_number] = result
    
    res = []
    print("These are the results of the completed futures:")
    for key, value in sorted(results.items()):
        print(f"Page number: {key}, result: {value}")
        res.extend(value)
    
    return res[:max_count] # Only return at most max_count items

max_items = 10
items = get_all_items(max_items)
print(f"get_all_items({max_items}) returned {len(items)} items:")
for item in items:
    print(item)

max_items = 100
items = get_all_items(max_items)
print(f"get_all_items({max_items}) returned {len(items)} items:")
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
Count: 6
Count: 12
These are the results of the completed futures:
Page number: 0, result: ['Result 0 in page 0.', 'Result 1 in page 0.', 'Result 2 in page 0.', 'Result 3 in page 0.', 'Result 4 in page 0.', 'Result 5 in page 0.']
Page number: 1, result: ['Result 0 in page 1.', 'Result 1 in page 1.', 'Result 2 in page 1.', 'Result 3 in page 1.', 'Result 4 in page 1.', 'Result 5 in page 1.']
get_all_items(10) returned 10 items:
Result 0 in page 0.
Result 1 in page 0.
Result 2 in page 0.
Result 3 in page 0.
Result 4 in page 0.
Result 5 in page 0.
Result 0 in page 1.
Result 1 in page 1.
Result 2 in page 1.
Result 3 in page 1.
Count: 6
Count: 12
Count: 18
Count: 24
Count: 24
Successfully cancelled future for page 7 <Future at 0x199ddb2ec50 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 8 <Future at 0x199ddb2e7f0 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 9 <Future at 0x199ddb2e860 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 11 <Future at 0x199ddb2e940 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 12 <Future at 0x199ddb2e198 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 13 <Future at 0x199ddb2e390 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 14 <Future at 0x199ddb2e9e8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 15 <Future at 0x199ddb2e6d8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 16 <Future at 0x199ddb2e630 state=cancelled>
Count: 24
Successfully cancelled future for page 7 <Future at 0x199ddb2ec50 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 8 <Future at 0x199ddb2e7f0 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 9 <Future at 0x199ddb2e860 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 11 <Future at 0x199ddb2e940 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 12 <Future at 0x199ddb2e198 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 13 <Future at 0x199ddb2e390 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 14 <Future at 0x199ddb2e9e8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 15 <Future at 0x199ddb2e6d8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 16 <Future at 0x199ddb2e630 state=cancelled>



Count: 24
Successfully cancelled future for page 7 <Future at 0x199ddb2ec50 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 8 <Future at 0x199ddb2e7f0 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 9 <Future at 0x199ddb2e860 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 11 <Future at 0x199ddb2e940 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 12 <Future at 0x199ddb2e198 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 13 <Future at 0x199ddb2e390 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 14 <Future at 0x199ddb2e9e8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 15 <Future at 0x199ddb2e6d8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 16 <Future at 0x199ddb2e630 state=cancelled>






Count: 24
Successfully cancelled future for page 7 <Future at 0x199ddb2ec50 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 8 <Future at 0x199ddb2e7f0 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 9 <Future at 0x199ddb2e860 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 11 <Future at 0x199ddb2e940 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 12 <Future at 0x199ddb2e198 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 13 <Future at 0x199ddb2e390 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 14 <Future at 0x199ddb2e9e8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 15 <Future at 0x199ddb2e6d8 state=cancelled>
Successfully cancelled future for page 16 <Future at 0x199ddb2e630 state=cancelled>
These are the results of the completed futures:
Page number: 0, result: ['Result 0 in page 0.', 'Result 1 in page 0.', 'Result 2 in page 0.', 'Result 3 in page 0.', 'Result 4 in page 0.', 'Result 5 in page 0.']
Page number: 1, result: ['Result 0 in page 1.', 'Result 1 in page 1.', 'Result 2 in page 1.', 'Result 3 in page 1.', 'Result 4 in page 1.', 'Result 5 in page 1.']
Page number: 2, result: ['Result 0 in page 2.', 'Result 1 in page 2.', 'Result 2 in page 2.', 'Result 3 in page 2.', 'Result 4 in page 2.', 'Result 5 in page 2.']
Page number: 3, result: ['Result 0 in page 3.', 'Result 1 in page 3.', 'Result 2 in page 3.', 'Result 3 in page 3.', 'Result 4 in page 3.', 'Result 5 in page 3.']
Page number: 4, result: []
Page number: 5, result: []
Page number: 6, result: []
Page number: 10, result: []
get_all_items(100) returned 24 items:
Result 0 in page 0.
Result 1 in page 0.
Result 2 in page 0.
Result 3 in page 0.
Result 4 in page 0.
Result 5 in page 0.
Result 0 in page 1.
Result 1 in page 1.
Result 2 in page 1.
Result 3 in page 1.
Result 4 in page 1.
Result 5 in page 1.
Result 0 in page 2.
Result 1 in page 2.
Result 2 in page 2.
Result 3 in page 2.
Result 4 in page 2.
Result 5 in page 2.
Result 0 in page 3.
Result 1 in page 3.
Result 2 in page 3.
Result 3 in page 3.
Result 4 in page 3.
Result 5 in page 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

Its `submit` method allows us to schedule function to execute in the thread pool and return `Future` object, which we can store in a list and later iterate on it in the ordered manner.
Also, we can use `with` context manager and the thread pool will be automatically closed and cleaned after all futures returns the result.

An example to illustrate the approach.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
import random


def process_page(index):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 5))
    if index % 5 == 0:
        raise ValueError()  # emulate some failed


def process_all(max_count):
    future_list = []
    result = []
    need_break = False
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for index in range(max_count):
            future = executor.submit(process_page, index)
            future_list.append(future)

        for index, future in enumerate(future_list):
            try:
                if need_break:
                    future.cancel()
                else:
                    result.append(future.result())
                    print(f"Page {index} processed")

                    if index >= 22:
                        need_break = True  # emulate some end condition
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Page {index} failed to process")


process_all(100)
```

Output:

```
Page 0 failed to process
Page 1 processed
Page 2 processed
Page 3 processed
Page 4 processed
Page 5 failed to process
Page 6 processed
Page 7 processed
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can create a simple array based on number of pages.
here is the pseudo code,

```
pages[] = new Array[totalPages];
while(pageCounter < totalPages):
     // Initiate an async thread to get the page data by sharing the array and its index.
     // Add the created thread to the same threadgroup so that we can close the thread pool after all the threads got finished

// In the thread after getting the page content push the page into that specific index like below,
       // get the page data
       pageArray[pageIndex] = pageData;
```

after all those threads got completed your pages got ordered automatically.
you dont worry about that.
Hope this idea helps you some what.
Insteaded of array even you can try it out with list as well with insert at the specified index like in array.